# Sorting a Recyclerview list dynamically

Tags: android, sorting, dynamic

I have a recyclerview list that is a check list. I want it to be sorted based on date and if the checkbox is checked or not. So if the user is on the main screen he/she should see a sorted list based on date and if he/she clicks a checkbox, I want that item to go the bottom of the list.

I wrote a compareTo method in the model class:

```
public int compareTo(BucketItem o) {
    if (this.isChecked && !o.isChecked){
        return -1;
    }else if(!this.isChecked && o.isChecked){
        return 1;
    }else if (this.isChecked && o.isChecked){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return getDate().compareTo(o.getDate());
    }
}
```

The layout looks for one item looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="13dp"
    android:paddingBottom="13dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/contact_name"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
        <!--/>-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.95">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="itemClicked"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bucket_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="editItem"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:id="@+id/bucket_des"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_name"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox1" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My main question is where do I put the Collections.sort(list) so that it gets called every time a new item gets added to the list or a checkbox gets checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in your Adapter class and put `Collections.sort(list)` followed by `notifyDataSetChanged` in that class.

```
void update(){
Collections.sort(list);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now call this method whenever any new item is added or checkbox is checked/un-checked.

```
CheckBox checkBox1;
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b)      {
   adapter.update();
    }
  });
```

Comment: While clicking the checkbox does move the item, it doesnt actually end up moving the checked items to the bottom. the list sort is basically not working as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: this is not what u have mentioned in your question

Answer (score -1):

I think you don't need to think about sorting the recycler view, instead you should sort the dataset with your required event and notify the recycler view by calling `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`